# irreps of $p^3$-group is faithful representation

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an irreps of  $p^3$-group. Prove that  $A$ is faithful representation.

I know that $p^2$-group and $p$-group are abelian.
I have to show, that $Ker A=e$

I have no idea how to start it

Comment: @Konstantin Ardakov.Yes, there is restriction $dim A \neq 1$ in my book. is $G/kerA \cong Im A $ in this case?(I mean $\cong$ is isomorphism).

Comment: yes, but its order is $1$ or $p$ or $p^2$ since $\ker A$ is non-trivial. So it's abelian as you know. And finite abelian groups only have one-dimensional irreducible complex representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false if $\dim A = 1$.

Suppose $\dim A > 1$ and that $\ker A$ is non-trivial. What do you know about irreducible representations of $G / \ker A$ in this case?